# What is the use of resolve in promise in nodejs

Tags: node.js, promise, callback

```
function getAuthSecrets() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let authSecrets = NamespaceManager.getNamespace('******).get('authSecrets');
        if (!authSecrets) {
            sm.getSecret(authConfig.secretName).then((secret) => {
                NamespaceManager.getNamespace('cls2_context').set('authSecrets', secret);
                resolve(secret);
            }).catch((error) => {
                reject(error);
            });
        } else {
            resolve(authSecrets);
        }
    });
}
```

Here it gets called :

```
if (username && password) {
            getAuthSecrets().then(secrets => {
```

What will get returned by calling getAuthSecret?

Comment: getAuthSecrets returns a promise of whatever gets passed to resolve or reject. What that is depends on which branch the function goes down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`authSecrets` or `secret`, depending on which call to `resolve` gets executed.

You want to `return resolve(...)` to avoid writing code that tries to resolve twice.

That you are catching then immediately rejecting is a sign that your machinery is more complex than it needs to be. You can lift a value to the Promise context with `Promise.resolve`:

```
function getAuthSecrets() {
    const authSecrets = NamespaceManager.getNamespace('******).get('authSecrets');
    return authSecrets ? Promise.resolve(authSecrets) :
      sm.getSecret(authConfig.secretName).then((secret) => {
        NamespaceManager.getNamespace('cls2_context').set('authSecrets', secret);
        return Promise.resolve(secret);
       })
    });
}
```